# DateTimePicker pain in the Bu.. I want to disable it if the previous conditions are not equal

Tags: c#, datetime, listbox, datetimepicker

I have a old time sheet application with historical data, the hr would like to view the old data once in a while, so i was given the task to build an c# application that would do so. first the user selects a paygroup drop down, chooses a pay group, based on the paygroup select the employees drop down get populated, then i have two text box one containing the min date and another containing you guessed it right a max date, Then i have two datetimepickers fromdate and to date. the datetimepicker gets its value from the mindate date box and max date text box, after all the items are selected the user clicks run report and the report is generated.

For a visual please click this -> [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEsLl.jpg)

**My Question is  I want to set the visibility of the datetimepickers to false if there are no dates available like in this -> [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNadz.jpg) as you can see the dates dont change because the datetimepickers can't set itself equal to an empty string so to work around that i just want the user to not even see the datetimepickers**

My Code that i tried:

```
 private void mindateset() // fill the listbox of values of mindate and maxdate
        {
            if (Employee.SelectedValue != null)
            {
                if (Employee.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim().Length > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (MSSQL.SqlConnection connection = new MSSQL.SqlConnection(constr))
                        {

                            timepunchnew = new EtimeHistoryDataSet();
                            connection.Open();
                            using (MSSQL.SqlCommand command = new MSSQL.SqlCommand("SELECT MIN(TransDate) AS mindate, MAX(TransDate) AS maxdate FROM dbo.EtimePunchDetail WHERE (EmpID = @empid)", connection))
                            {

                                MSSQL.SqlParameter myminparam = new MSSQL.SqlParameter();
                                myminparam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                                myminparam.ParameterName = "@empid";

                                myminparam.Value = Employee.SelectedValue;
                                command.Parameters.Add(myminparam);

                                MSSQL.SqlDataAdapter myadapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
                                myadapter.SelectCommand = command;
                                myadapter.Fill(timepunchnew, "Mindate");
                                AvailableMin.DataSource = timepunchnew.Mindate;
                                AvailableMin.DisplayMember = "mindate";
                                AvailableMax.DataSource = timepunchnew.Mindate;
                                AvailableMax.DisplayMember = "maxdate";
                                FromDate.MinDate = DateTime.Parse(AvailableMin.Text);
                                FromDate.Value = FromDate.MinDate;
                                if (FromDate.Value != FromDate.MinDate)
                                {
                                    if (DialogResult.OK == MessageBox.Show("The Selected User Does Not Have Any FromDate"))
                                    {
                                        FromDate.Visible = false;

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        FromDate.Value = FromDate.MinDate;
                                        FromDate.Visible = true;
                                    }

                                }
                                ToDate.MaxDate = DateTime.Parse(AvailableMax.Text);
                                ToDate.Value = ToDate.MaxDate;
                                if (ToDate.Value != ToDate.MaxDate)

                                        if (DialogResult.OK == MessageBox.Show("The Selected User Does Not Have Any FromDate"))
                                        {
                                            ToDate.Visible = false;

                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            ToDate.Value = ToDate.MinDate;
                                            ToDate.Visible = true;
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
```

**ANY HELP WITH THIS WILL BE APPRECIATED, THIS IS THE LAST STEP IN MY PROJECT**

Comment: You set ToDate.Value = ToDate.MaxDate and then check ToDate.Value != ToDate.MaxDate? Same with From?

Comment: @starlight54 Yea when ToDate.Value = ToDate.MaxDate everything is good, but when ToDate.Value != ToDate.MaxDate because the person does not have dates then the availablemax and min listbox become blank but when the availablemax and min listboxes have a date then i set that datevalue to that of the datetimepicker as a max or min date. i saw a workaround online, they say to place a text box over the datetimepicker value and make the textbox visible each time ToDate.Value != ToDate.MaxDate

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, although it looks like you're living up to you're name with it :D I was just saying that setting ToDate.Value = ToDate.MaxDate and then doing if (ToDate.Value != ToDate.MaxDate) is pointless, because of course that if will always be false, you just set them equal the line before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created two textboxes and placed it over the datetimepicker value and make it visible if there is not date available from the listbox :)

```
private void AvailableMin_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (AvailableMin.Text == "")
            {
                textBox2.Visible = true;
                textBox2.Text = "There are no to dates available for this particular user";
            }
            else
            {
                textBox2.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        private void AvailableMax_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (AvailableMax.Text == "")
            {
                textBox1.Visible = true;
                textBox1.Text = "There are no to dates available for this particular user";
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```